# rosluanch turtlebot_bring minimal.launch

Tags: roslaunch, ubuntu, ubuntu-precise, turtlebot-bringup, ros-groovy

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have some errors when I "rosluanch turtlebot_bring minimal.launch"
Following message is the error message::

```
while processing /opt/ros/groovy/ros_catkin_ws/install_isolated/share/turtlebot/turtlebot_bringup/launch/includes/_robot.launch:
Invalid <arg> tag: xacro
ROS path [0]=/opt/ros/groovy/ros_catkin_ws/install_isolated/share/ros
ROS path [1]=/opt/ros/groovy/ros_catkin_ws/install_isolated/share/turtlebot
ROS path [2]=/opt/ros/groovy/ros_catkin_ws/install_isolated/share/turtlebot/
ROS path [3]=/opt/ros/groovy/ros_catkin_ws/install_isolated/share/turtlebot
ROS path [4]=/opt/ros/groovy/ros_catkin_ws/install_isolated/share
ROS path [5]=/opt/ros/groovy/ros_catkin_ws/install_isolated/stacks.
Arg xml is <arg default="$(find xacro)/xacro.py '$(find turtlebot_description)/robots/$(arg base)_$(arg stacks)_$(arg 3d_sensor).urdf.xacro'" name="urdf_file"/>
```

Dose anyone can help to solve it. Thank you very much!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/62940/rosluanch-turtlebot_bring-minimal.launch/) by [CharlesLiou](https://answers.ros.org/users/4877/charlesliou/) on ROS Answers with karma: 16 on 2013-05-16

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [CarolineQ](https://answers.ros.org/users/4109/carolineq/) on 2013-05-17**:
Do you have the packages turtlebot_description and xacro installed on your system ?

**Comment by [mjcarroll](https://answers.ros.org/users/9/mjcarroll/) on 2013-05-20**:
Can you explain what operating system you are on?  Your path seems to indicate that you did a source install on your system.  I believe that you will have a much easier time using the precompiled binaries if you are using Ubuntu.

**Comment by [CharlesLiou](https://answers.ros.org/users/4877/charlesliou/) on 2013-05-21**:
Thank you for your response. My operating system is Ubuntu 12.04, but I don't know what you mean "Your path seems to indicate that you did .... precompiled binaries if you are using Ubuntu". Can you explain more detail? Thank you.

**Comment by [mjcarroll](https://answers.ros.org/users/9/mjcarroll/) on 2013-05-22**:
Are you using Ubuntu on a normal x86/x64 computer?  If that is the case, then you should follow the instructions here to install ROS: http://ros.org/wiki/groovy/Installation/Ubuntu

**Comment by [CharlesLiou](https://answers.ros.org/users/4877/charlesliou/) on 2013-05-22**:
I use ubuntu on PandaBoard and follow the tutorial to install ROS: http://www.ros.org/wiki/groovy/Installation/PandaBoard/Source

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Thank you, CarolineQ.
I have turtlebot_description package and install xacro package after your suggestion. Then, I launch "rosluanch turtlebot_bring minimal.launch" again. But still have some error when I launch. Following message is the error message::

The bold type is the all message when I launch "rosluanch turtlebot_bring minimal.launch"

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/ros/groovy/ros_catkin_ws/install_isolated/share/xacro/xacro.py", line 35, in <module>
    xacro.main()
  File "/opt/ros/groovy/ros_catkin_ws/install_isolated/share/xacro/src/xacro.py", line 554, in main
    process_includes(doc, os.path.dirname(sys.argv[1]))
  File "/opt/ros/groovy/ros_catkin_ws/install_isolated/share/xacro/src/xacro.py", line 193, in process_includes
    filename = eval_text(elt.getAttribute('filename'), {})
  File "/opt/ros/groovy/ros_catkin_ws/install_isolated/share/xacro/src/xacro.py", line 409, in eval_text
    results.append(handle_extension(lex.next()[1][2:-1]))
  File "/opt/ros/groovy/ros_catkin_ws/install_isolated/share/xacro/src/xacro.py", line 397, in handle_extension
    return eval_extension("$(%s)" % s)
  File "/opt/ros/groovy/ros_catkin_ws/install_isolated/share/xacro/src/xacro.py", line 53, in eval_extension
    return substitution_args.resolve_args(str, resolve_anon=False)
  File "/opt/ros/groovy/ros_catkin_ws/install_isolated/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/roslaunch/substitution_args.py", line 208, in resolve_args
    resolved = _find(resolved, a, args, context)
  File "/opt/ros/groovy/ros_catkin_ws/install_isolated/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/roslaunch/substitution_args.py", line 144, in _find
    return resolved[0:idx-len(arg)] + r.get_path(args[0]) + resolved[idx:]
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rospkg-1.0.19-py2.7.egg/rospkg/rospack.py", line 164, in get_path**

**raise ResourceNotFound(name, ros_paths=self._ros_paths) rospkg.common.ResourceNotFound: create_description**

**ROS path [0]=/opt/ros/groovy/ros_catkin_ws/install_isolated/share/ros
ROS path [1]=/opt/ros/groovy/ros_catkin_ws/install_isolated/share
ROS path [2]=/opt/ros/groovy/ros_catkin_ws/install_isolated/stacks
while processing /opt/ros/groovy/ros_catkin_ws/install_isolated/share/turtlebot/turtlebot_bringup/launch/includes/_robot.launch:**
**Invalid <param> tag: Cannot load command parameter [robot_description]: command [/opt/ros/groovy/ros_catkin_ws/install_isolated/share/xacro/xacro.py '/opt/ros/groovy/ros_catkin_ws/install_isolated/share/turtlebot/turtlebot_description/robots/kobuki_hexagons_kinect.urdf.xacro'] returned with code [1].
Param xml is < param command="$(arg urdf_file)" name="robot_description"/>
```

---

Originally posted by [CharlesLiou](https://answers.ros.org/users/4877/charlesliou/) with karma: 16 on 2013-05-17

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [CarolineQ](https://answers.ros.org/users/4109/carolineq/) on 2013-05-20**:
Don't you have any other message before this one ? I mean, I got this error few times, most of the time there was another line before that saying "package X is missing". This package could be for example kobuki_description... Did you install ROS with a full install ?

**Comment by [CharlesLiou](https://answers.ros.org/users/4877/charlesliou/) on 2013-05-21**:
The bold type is the all message when I launch "rosluanch turtlebot_bring minimal.launch", but it doesn't seem to miss package. I follow this tutorial "http://www.ros.org/wiki/groovy/Installation/PandaBoard/Source" to install ROS.

**Comment by [CharlesLiou](https://answers.ros.org/users/4877/charlesliou/) on 2013-05-21**:
In the tutorial step 3.1.1 Create a catkin Workspace, I install Robot (not ROS_Comm)

**Comment by [CarolineQ](https://answers.ros.org/users/4109/carolineq/) on 2013-05-21**:
"ResourceNotFound: create_description" : You need to install the create_description package.

**Comment by [CharlesLiou](https://answers.ros.org/users/4877/charlesliou/) on 2013-05-22**:
Thank CarolineQ! I already install create_description package.Then, another error: "ResourceNotFound: kobuki_description". But I can't install this package, I download this package from here "http://www.ros.org/wiki/kobuki_description", using "git clone".

**Comment by [CharlesLiou](https://answers.ros.org/users/4877/charlesliou/) on 2013-05-22**:
After download it, I export ros path to "kobuki". But i still can't find "kobuki_description" package when I use "rospack find kobuki_description"

**Comment by [CarolineQ](https://answers.ros.org/users/4109/carolineq/) on 2013-05-22**:
Maybe you need to build the package kobuki_description with make or rosmake. If you are using Ubuntu, is it not possible to do "sudo apt-get install kobuki" ?

**Comment by [CharlesLiou](https://answers.ros.org/users/4877/charlesliou/) on 2013-05-24**:
Sorry, I don't know how to build the package which I use "git clone" from here "http://www.ros.org/wiki/kobuki"...

**Comment by [CarolineQ](https://answers.ros.org/users/4109/carolineq/) on 2013-05-26**:
You can go into the package kobuki_description and try to do a rosmake.
But before that did you try to do "sudo apt-get install kobuki" ?

**Comment by [CharlesLiou](https://answers.ros.org/users/4877/charlesliou/) on 2013-05-27**:
I think I find the reason why I can't rosmake "kobuki_description". Because the "kobuki_description" folder doesn't have "Makefile". On the other hand, I can't use "sudo apt-get install kobuki" to install kobuki, this is error I get "Unable to locate package kobuki"